# How to define Firebase?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angular-seed

Im trying to learn Angular and the video tutorial I am doing is using Firebase, Ive got Firebase defined as

```
//Contacts controller
.controller('ContactsCtrl', ['$scope', '$firebaseArray', function($scope, $firebaseArray) {
  //init firebase
  var ref = new Firebase('https://myappurl-048596.firebaseio.com/');
```

but when viewing the console, I keep getting errors saying Firebase not defined and it breaks the whole project. So, how do I properly define Firebase so that I can get rid of this error?

Comment: I believe it's `firebase`, lowercase. https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start

Comment: i just tried that and now im getting a different error: firebase is not a constructor.

Comment: In the tutorial I am working on, they have firebase capitalized and its working perfectly fine for them.

Comment: That's because it's not a constructor. If you read those docs, you initialize Firebase with `firebase.initialize()`. Sounds like the tutorial is using an old version of Firebase. The docs don't lie.

Answer (score 0):

1. Follow this link: https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup
2. Add this in your config function:

   ```
   var firebaseConfig = {
       apiKey: "<API_KEY>",
       authDomain: "<PROJECT_ID>.firebaseapp.com",
       databaseURL: "https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com",
       storageBucket: "<BUCKET>.appspot.com",
       messagingSenderId: "<SENDER_ID>",
   };

   firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
   ```